# angular2 - HTTP post request parameters are null

Tags: angular, http-post

i am trying to call a HTTP post method like this. It is working fine in local development and have issues in production.

```
let URL = url;
let body = { tenantId, branchId };
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this._http.post(URL, body, options).map(res => res.json()).
  catch(error => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
```

But when i get these parameters in the server side, the values are becoming null.What might be the reason?
Help me on this. Thanks

Comment: Try stringifying the body: let body = JSON.stringify({ tenantId, branchId });, see if it helps

Comment: yes i tried. But it did't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The proble is with your body object. It is not a valid object.

`let body = { tenantId, branchId };`

It should be something like:

`let body = { tenantId: 123, branchId: 123 };`. You are not assing any value to the object properties.

You don't need to stringfy...

Comment: Nice catch.. ^^

Comment: No. It's not working for me. In local it's fine. But in production it's not working.

Comment: If work in local env should also work in production. I think you did not update the production app or the body is an invalid object there...

Comment: @vinagreti  - I did everything, but did't help me. Any other suggestion?

Comment: I can think in many reasons but I'll suggest you to look at your http call to see if the data are sent or not. If the data are sent, the problem is in your back-end, if not, is in your front-end. That is a good start point. After that, I can help you more. Please, update you question with this info!

Comment: @vinagreti - Thank you. But i used some different approach. It worked for me. I used UrlSearchParams and i removed the Content-Type.

Comment: Did you use `UrlSearchParams` with POST call? I think you were doing this wwrong. There are a difference between POST and GET. Post send body data (payload) and GEt send Url parameters. If you are using `UrlSearchParams` to send data via POST, you are making a security vulnerability once all data are going to be passed via URL. Another problem is that you have only 2048 char limit on url and if your data is too big, you won't send the entire data. Looking at your answer, I think you were getting UrlParams instead data in your backend and that is why you didn't see it there.